# Lazy Loading Issue | Spartacus 2.0.0

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I am trying to implement lazy loading feature using Spartacus 2.0 but facing below issues:

1. Templates are not getting visible after it is loaded at very first
   time.
2. Components are getting visible when we again come back to same page.
3. Also some components are getting visible only after I resize the
   screen once after page is loaded.

We are using below strategy mentioned at below location for component lazy loading

https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/lazy-loading-guide/

Here is code snippet for one of the module file:

```
 Module1,
 Module2,
 ConfigModule.withConfig({
   cmsComponents: {
     ComponentABC: {
      component: () =>
        import('./xyz.component').then(
          (m) => m.xyz
       )
     }
   }
 }),
 storefrontModule
],
```

Please suggest for possible solutions.

Comment: Could you update your Spartacus version to 2.0.9 and verify again?
And then in 3.1 - if you can see still the issue, please create an github issue with more details.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should looks like:

```
ConfigModule.withConfig({
  cmsComponents: {
    ABCComponent: {
      component: ABCComponent,
    },
    XYZComponent: {
      component: () => import('./xyz.component').then(m => m.XYZComponent)
    }
  }
}),
```

Comment: hi Michal. Thanks for reply. We are using the same strategy which you have mentioned. I have updated code snippet to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

For using lazy loading with Spartacus version 2.0, the 2.x lazy loading guide may be more appropriate: https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/2.x/lazy-loading-guide/